# responsive design: weird layout display on small devices and Iphone

Tags: iphone, responsive-design

I have a weird problem, I hope somebody can help.

I have designed this responsive [site](http://musicplanner.es) and it works fine but on mobile phones it does a weird thing. Before the final site as it would be seen on a small screen it loads for a few milliseconds the site all messed up, with the sidebard above the main content, but afterwards it loads the right layout. 
I wasn't worrying too much abuot this but later I realized that on iphones you could only see the messed up site, not the proper layout as it should be.

My media queries are like this:

```
<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:50px) and (max-width:479px)"   href="css/screen-layout-small.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:480px) and (max-width:767px)"  href="css/screen-layout-medium.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width:768px) and (max-width:959px)"  href="css/screen-layout-large.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:200,300,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=2">
```

Hope someone can help as I'm going a bit out of my mind here. Thanks!

Comment: I think I fixed it. I changed my media queries from html to css instead and addressed iphone specifically with   
@media (device-height: 568px) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) {}   it seems to be working now

Comment: I am facing same problem..Can you tell me how you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I checked the site on my android phone now, i noticed this div( barritaloca) was not properly formatted in your media queries.
Its floating to the top page thereby causing the site to load abnormally.
You should correct that div and revert.
Meanwhile, post your css here for reveiew
Thanks

Comment: You could say this in the comment as it's not seems an answer.